# Is it necessary to set the id_of_setinterval variable to null after clearInterval(id_of_setinterval)?

Tags: javascript

```
var id_of_setinterval = setInterval(function(){}, 2000)

if(id_of_setinterval) {
    clearInterval(id_of_setinterval);
    id_of_setinterval = null; //Does it necessary? Why?
}
```

I really do not know why this code was written.

In my opinion, I think that setting id_of_setinterval to `null` is **unnecessary**.

Comment: No, that is absolutely not necessary.

Comment: Also harmful (change of type from Number to Object)

Comment: This sounds like a pattern to determine if an interval is currently running. If  `id_of_setinterval` is non-null, then that interval is running; otherwise it is not. Other parts of the code, not shown here, could use this information somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you use more than one timer and start and end some timer, then it is better to set it to zero, because it hold only an id of the timer, from [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

> The returned `timeoutID` is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to `setInterval();` this value can be passed to `Window.clearInterval()` to cancel the timeout.

**And** according to [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

> It's worth noting that the pool of IDs used by `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` are shared, which means you can technically use `clearInterval()` and `clearTimeout()` interchangeably. However, for clarity, you should avoid doing so.

If you use only one timer and one variable, then there is no need to set the id to zero.

Comment: But what harm is there to keep the `timeoutID` around? Calling `clear`* with a cleared `timeoutID` does nothing.

Comment: it's an id out of a pool. the id could have been used again, but for another purpose.